# Running multiple python files in different terminals/consoles from one python file

Tags: python, terminal, console

I have 5 python files which i need to run on different terminals/consoles. Currently what i'm doing is running each file on its own terminal/console `python filename.py`.

What i would like is to run one file that will run all the other files in different terminals/consoles.

I haven't tried anything yet. I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction on what to do.

Comment: Why not put the contents of the 5 files in 5 functions and call them one after another?

Comment: will that create 5 consoles with each running its file?

Comment: Nope. But you can write the outputs to a file if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the screen command, if it is not actually necessary that five different terminals pop up. Write a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dmS "screen-name-1" python filename1.py
screen -dmS "screen-name-2" python filename2.py
screen -dmS "screen-name-2" python filename2.py
```

Then you can access each screen with e.g.

```
screen -r screen-name-1
```

For details, see https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/