# How to run different python files in different terminals (each having different PIDs) from a single bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have 3 python files stored in different folders. I need these files to run in different terminals. I have also tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217888/running-multiple-python-files-in-different-terminals-consoles-from-one-python-fi) but this is not what I am trying to achieve. This is my code so far:

> RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.py

```
#!/bin/sh

###### STARTING UP NRF MODULE #####
sleep 2
cd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/NRF24L01
python NRF_MQTT.py
sleep 5
###################################

#### STARTING UP TEST MODULE 1 ####
cd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/TEST
python TEST_PUB_1.py
sleep 2
###################################

#### STARTING UP TEST MODULE 2 ####
cd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/TEST
python TEST_PUB_2.py
sleep 2
###################################
```

Comment: What is the end goal here? You say it's not what you're trying to achieve but don't explain why it isn't

Comment: I am not using that solution as it would make it difficult to debug the pythons.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am doing this on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch OS.

Comment: Have you tried `nohup python TEST_PUB_1.py &` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
#!/bin/sh

###### STARTING UP NRF MODULE #####
sleep 2
pushd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/NRF24L01
terminal -e python NRF_MQTT.py
pwd
sleep 5
###################################

#### STARTING UP TEST MODULE 1 ####
pushd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/TEST
terminal -e python TEST_PUB_1.py
sleep 2
pwd
###################################

#### STARTING UP TEST MODULE 2 ####
pushd Desktop/RPI_GATEWAY/TEST
terminal -e python TEST_PUB_2.py
sleep 2
pwd
###################################
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands

Comment: Im getting errors when executing this. The error is:  
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 5: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: pushd: not found
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 6: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: terminal: not found
/home/pi
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 13: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: pushd: not found
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 14: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: pushd: not found
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 15: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: terminal: not found
/home/pi
./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: 22: ./RPI_GATEWAY_LAUNCHER.sh: terminal: not found
/home/pi

Comment: read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the